# PHP variable declaration with JSON data envolved

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, mongodb

Hello I am trying to make a stocks diagram which will pull data from a mongodb and from a JSON stream. I am trying to display the current time read from the JSON stream into the graph using a PHP array but at some point I have an error with a variable declaration and the time fails to display on the X-axis of the graph. I am posting the point of the code that has the problem:

```
chart.xAxis 
        .tickFormat(
           formatter = function(d, i) {
             //var now = new Date((new Date()).getTime());
             //var now = new Date('12/03/2008 23:05:13' );
             var timejson = " . $time . ";
             var now = new Date(d);//timejson[0].datetime);
             d = d + 1
             //console.log(timejson[99].datetime);
                     return d3.time.format('%H:%M:%S')(now ); }
         );
```

And here is the json encode part : `$time = json_encode($time);`

Comment: The line var timejason =" . $time . "; is the one that has the bug.

Comment: i am just not able to get the correct time at the graph and i found that the only thing that can have the problem is here

Answer (score 0):

`$time` is a PHP variable, but you're trying to use it in a Javascript context. You need to indicate that you want `$time` to be evaluated on the server side by PHP, so you have to wrap it in PHP tags. This is how your line would look like:

```
var timejson = <?php echo $time ?>;
```